# How Can We Explain The Dependence of 'Magnetic Moment of Current Loop' On The Area of Loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

The Formula For Magnetic Moment of Current Carrying loop Is Defined As - **m = I.A**. How Can I Understand This Area Dependence i.e. If Area of Loop Is Doubled, Magnetic Moment Gets Doubled For Same Value of Current? What Happens When We Change Area of Loop That Affects Magnetic Moment?

Answer (score 0):

One measure of dipole moment is the torque which it experiences when placed in an external field.  A larger current loop will experience a larger torque.  Another measure is the strength of the field which the dipole produces at a given point.  A larger loop has more segments of current contributing to the field at each point.